# Migrating a Big Derby embebed database to HSQLDB throw java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, spring-boot, database-migration, derby, hsqldb

I'm trying to migrate a big db from derby to HSQLDB in a Spring Boot service, like 1.5M regs in few tables of 10 columns. I'm checking with VisualVM; byte and char consume a lot of memory. But the biggest delta in time are in the derby classes.

Sometimes the error is thrown here, but other times thrown in other controllers. I don't want to touch all files to add my catchOutofMemory to restart.

Following is a version of my code, the block comment shows the resume of the process:

```
run(){//thread inside static function.
    while(keepMigrating){
        keepMigrating=Migrate();
    }
}
private static boolean Migrate(JdbcTemplate derby,JdbcTemplate hsql){
    int regs = 100000;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement statementHSQL = null;
    try {
        for (String table : tables) {//tables contains all tables to migrate
        //check how many registers left asd asign to cant, if cant is 0 the empty is true.
        PreparedStatement statementUpd[];
            while (!empty) {
                if (trys <= 0) throw new Exception("redo");
                //check how many registers left asd asign to cant, if cant is 0 the empty is true and out of bucle and ready to check next table
                /*
                *Next process resume as:
                *fetch data from derby that hasnt been migrated limited by cant
                *create a batch to insert in hsql
                *create a update for derby
                *create a delete in case someting goes wrong
                *excecute insert and update, if someting in batch fail delete the entry in migrate table
                *reduce regs to get out of migrate method at some ponint.
                */
                statement = derby.getDataSource().getConnection().prepareStatement(
                MessageFormat.format(select_all_migrate_false_and_fetch_cant,table));
                statementUpd = new PreparedStatement[cant];
                ArrayList<String> deleteIds = new ArrayList<>();
                StringBuilder columnNames = new StringBuilder();
                StringBuilder updateSQL = new StringBuilder();
                StringBuilder bindVariables = new StringBuilder();
                try {
                    ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
                    for (int i = 1; i <= meta.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                        if (!meta.getColumnName(i).equals("MIGRATED")) {
                            if (i > 1) {
                                columnNames.append(", ");
                                bindVariables.append(", ");
                            }
                            columnNames.append(meta.getColumnName(i));
                            bindVariables.append('?');
                        }
                    }
                    String sql = "INSERT INTO " + table.substring(4) + " ("
                            + columnNames
                            + ") VALUES ("
                            + bindVariables
                            + ")";
                    statementHSQL = hsql.getDataSource().getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
                    HashMap<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
                    int row = 0;
                    int lastId = 0;
                    String columnName;
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        for (int i = 1; i <= meta.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                            columnName = meta.getColumnName(i);
                            Object o = rs.getObject(i);
                            statementHSQL.setObject(i, o);
                            if (columnName.equals(mainColumn))
                                deleteIds.add(String.valueOf(o));
                            if (!(meta.getColumnType(i) == 2004)) data.put(columnName, o);
                            if (columnName.equals(mainColumn)) id = rs.getObject(i);
                        }
                        int c = 1;
                        String update = MessageFormat.format("INSERT INTO {0}M ({1}M, MIGRATED) VALUES(?, TRUE)",
                                table.substring(4), mainColumn).replace("\"M", "M\"");//migrated state is saved in other table
                        lastId = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(id));
                        statementUpd[row] = derby.getDataSource().getConnection().prepareStatement(update);
                        statementUpd[row].setObject(1, rs.getObject(mainColumn));
                        updateSQL = new StringBuilder();
                        statementHSQL.addBatch();
                        row += 1;
                    }
                    /*
                     * Build delete query in case of inserted values in HSQLDB but not updated in DERBY
                     */
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                    builder.append("(");
                    int count = 1;
                    for (String s : deleteIds) {
                        if (count > 1) builder.append(", ");
                        builder.append("?");
                        count++;
                    }
                    builder.append(")");
                    String str = builder.toString();
                    String queryDelete = "DELETE FROM " + table.substring(4) + " WHERE " + mainColumn + " IN " + str;
                    PreparedStatement statementHSQLDel = hsql.getDataSource().getConnection().prepareStatement
                            (queryDelete);
                    int c = 1;
                    for (String s : deleteIds) {
                        statementHSQLDel.setObject(c, s);
                        c++;
                    }
                    boolean deletes = statementHSQLDel.execute();
                    statementHSQLDel.close();
                    try {
                        DatabaseUtils.close(statementHSQLDel);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        catchOutOfMemory(e);
                    }
                    int[] result = statementHSQL.executeBatch();
                    StringBuilder resultS = new StringBuilder();
                    int stCounter = 0;
                    int stCounterInsert = 0;
                    int stCounterUpdate = 0;
                    String notarydebug;
                    for (int i : result) {
                        int upd = 0;
                        try {
                            if (i == 1) upd = statementUpd[stCounter].executeUpdate();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            catchOutOfMemory(e);
                        }
                        stCounterInsert += i;
                        stCounterUpdate += upd;
                        resultS.append(",").append(String.valueOf(i)).append("-").append(String.valueOf(upd));
                        stCounter += 1;
                    }
                    statementHSQL.clearBatch();
                    try {
                        DatabaseUtils.close(statementHSQL);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        catchOutOfMemory(e);
                    }
                } catch (SQLException se) {
                    catchOutOfMemory(se);//otherstuff
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    catchOutOfMemory(e);
                }
                try {
                    DatabaseUtils.close(rs);
                    DatabaseUtils.close(statement);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    catchOutOfMemory(e);
                }
                regs=regs-cant;
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        if (e.getMessage().equals("redo")) return true;//end the loop of regs maximun and get out of method.
    }
return false;//end migration succesfully
}
private static int catchOutOfMemory(Throwable e) {
    if (e == null) return 0;
    if (e instanceof OutOfMemoryError) {
        Application.restartBat();
        return 1;
    } else {
        return catchOutOfMemory(e.getCause());
    }
}
```

edit:
So I change as sugested inthe comment to accept a commit, something like this:

```
Connection hsqlCon;
PrepareStatement hsqlStm;
hsqlCon = JdbcHSQLDB.getDataSource().getConnection();
hsqlStm = hsqlCon.prepareStatement(sql);
hsqlStm.addBatch();
hsqlStm.execute();
hsqlStm.close();
hsqlCon.close();
```

but i got the same heap memory consumpsion:
 [image]

Comment: What URL are you using for HSQLDB? Are you using the in-memory URL instead of file-based?

Comment: bot DERBY and HSQLDB are files

Comment: The only other problem I see is that you aren't correctly closing connections and statements when you've used them (although your code is hard to follow given its structure), which cause more objects in memory than necessary.

Comment: Thanks @Mark, I'll double check one by one again if an statement keep open, I was using null in some points and found one.

Comment: You need to do this kind of transfer in multiple transactions and commit each transaction. HSQLDB keeps the uncommitted rows in memory, which can run out if the database is large.

Comment: This isn't simply an OOM question. The database is a file database. The size of the transactions and the batches need to be controlled when transferring 1.5 million rows.

Comment: hi fredt, each batch is about 1000and I tried to change the batch to array of prepared statements and get worse, now I control with a limited trys of 300k-600k and then restart the service when is in low demand.

Comment: Rewrite and use a single parametric PreparedStatement for the insert. Then use the addBatch() method to add the inserted data to the PreparedStatement. After 1000 rows, call executeBatch() and commit.

Comment: I use that in the code I pasted here, but I'm missing the commit.

Answer (score 0):

The type of table in HSQLDB is not clear from the supplied code. You must use this statement once for each table, to make sure the table data is stored in the `finename.data` file:

```
SET TABLE tableName TYPE CACHED
```

The reported sequence of batch INSERT is not correct. Use this sequence:

```
Connection hsqlCon;
PrepareStatement hsqlStm;
hsqlCon = JdbcHSQLDB.getDataSource().getConnection();
hsqlStm = hsqlCon.prepareStatement(sql);

{ // repeat this block until all is finished
    { // repeat for 1000 rows
        hsqlStm.addBatch();
    } 
    hsqlStm.executeBatch(); // after every 1000 rows
} 

hsqlStm.close();
hsqlCon.close();
```